# Strong Induction (verify solution of linear recurrence)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, exponentiation

I am trying to prove a statement using strong induction but I seem to be getting stuck. I don't know if did something wrong or I am just not recognizing an opportunity for factoring/how to factor numbers with rational exponents. Here is the prompt:

Let $ a_0, a_1, a_2, ...$ be a sequence such that $a_0 = 2, a_1 = 6$ and $a_k = 6a_{k−1} − 8a_{k−2}$ for $k ≥ 2.$ Prove that $a_n = 2^n(2^n + 1)$ for all $n ≥ 0. $

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the statement holds for all $n<k$. Let's look at $a_k$.

By definition, $a_k=6a_{k-1}-8a_{k-2}$.

What does the induction hypothesis tell you about $a_{k-1}$?

What does the induction hypothesis tell you about $a_{k-2}$?

---

Note that for this to really make sense, I need $k\ge 2$ (since $a_0$ and $a_1$ are defined differently). So really, the full proof needs to also include calculations for $k=0$ and $k=1$; but that's not hard.

Answer (score 1):

If
$a_k = 6a_{k−1} − 8a_{k−2}
$
and
$a_n = 2^n(2^n + 1)
$
for
$n=k-1$ and $k-2$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
a_k 
&= 6a_{k−1} − 8a_{k−2}\\
&= 6(2^{k-1}(2^{k-1} + 1)) − 8(2^{k-2}(2^{k-2} + 1))\\
&= 6(2^{2k-2}+2^{k-1}) − 8(2^{2k-4}+2^{k-2})\\
&= 3(2^{2k-1}+2^{k}) − (2^{2k-1}+2^{k+1})\\
&= 3\cdot 2^{2k-1}+3\cdot 2^{k} − 2^{2k-1}-2^{k+1}\\
&= 2\cdot 2^{2k-1}+2^{k+1}+ 2^{k}-2^{k+1}
\qquad\text{(using }3=2+1)\\
&=  2^{2k}+ 2^{k}\\
&=  2^{k}(2^{k}+1)\\
\end{array}
$

and we are done.

Not sophisticated,
but not trivial.

Note that we need the result
true for k-1 and k-2
to show that it is true
for k.

I would call this
"weak strong induction"
since I usually interpret
"strong induction"
to assuming that
it is true for
all j < k,
not just the
preceding two values.